# How is the extent of the rings of J1407b, a "Super Saturn," compatible with the Roche limit?

Tags: exoplanet, planetary-ring, roche-limit

[J1407](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V1400_Centauri#J1407b) is a Sun-like star in Centaurus. Astronomers observed its exoplanet J1407b pass before it over several weeks and the details of the light curves indicate the exoplanet has over thirty rings, each tens of millions of miles in diameter, roughly two hundred times those of Saturn. How is the extent of the rings of this "Super Saturn" compatible with the Roche limit? This strikes me as a puzzle similar to what is observed with, in our Solar System, the minor planet [50000 Quaoar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50000_Quaoar), which has a ring system beyond the Roche limit, thus at a distance from its planet at which we would expect the ring components to either coalesce and form a moon or disperse, rather than persist as a ring system.